# Monitor activity of a specific CPU core on Linux

Tags: linux, performance

I have a performance issue in my application. I have a critical thread running on a specific cpu core (its affinity is set to this cpu core). It always performs the same task in a loop. But from time to time, the loop takes more time than it should.
This might be due to the code of the application itself or to some external factors (like other processes running on the same cpu core).
I would like to be able to create some kind of timeline of things that run on this core (which process, which thread and ideally which function).
What do you recommend me to use to do this? (I am working on Linux)

Thanks in advance,

Serb.

Comment: Why not simply remove the affinity and let the critical thread to run on any available CPU? Raise its priority instead if response time is of importance. And of course, look for bottlenecks or other non-CPU related delays.

Comment: You can prevent the scheduler from using that core for other tasks by reserving it on the kernel command line.